# local redis = require "resty.redis" do not support redis cluster in openresty?

Tags: redis, lua, openresty

I try to operate redis data according to this web: https://moonbingbing.gitbooks.io/openresty-best-practices/content/redis/auth_connect.html. But I find that local redis = require "resty.redis" do not support redis cluster.
Do Lua have any official tool that support Redis cluster operations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you want to have a look at the [lua-resty-redis-cluster](https://luarocks.org/modules/membphis/lua-resty-redis-cluster) lua module.

Hint: It's the first 3 matches if you google "resty.redis cluster" ;)